# How to convert an array of string to CSV string with commas?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of string

```
["Ann", "David", "Ben"]
```

How can I convert to CSV string in javascript?

```
"Ann, David, Ben"
```

Comment: [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).  Specifically, `.join(',')`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join()` will do it for you. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
a=["Ann", "David", "Ben"]

a.join()
"Ann,David,Ben"
```

Comment: Unless it's a mistake, note that OP seems to want strings to be separated with `", "` (comma followed by a single whitespace). So you should be using `join(', ')` instead of `join()`.